# When I include a static library "libupnpx.a" in my project that is 6 MB, does this make my app 6 MB larger?

Tags: static-libraries, static-linking

I have heard the compiler strips out unused code. But when I include a `libupnpx.a` static library archive of 6 MB, will this make app 6 MB larger? Or is this same as including the library source code directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generally expect that static linking and "including the library source code directly" will have equivalent impacts on the size of the resulting executable. There are be some minor cases in which this may not be strictly true, but generally speaking, they should be approximately equivalent.

Comment: Does the 6 MB of the .a file mean the actual binary becomes 6 MB larger, or is this still source code only?

Comment: Not sure how to explain this differently: If the compilation of the library yields 6MB of object code, I would expect it to do so regardless of whether it is compiled separately as a library and then statically linked into the executable, or if it is compiled directly into the executable without the intermediate step of generating a library.

Comment: this is not correct. when you link with an archive only the objects (.o) that are required to resolve the symbols are used. this is why it was customary to put one symbol (function or global variable) per .c file in building libraries; the impact is not equivalent to the size of the full archive ( library )

Comment: What's your argument here? That there's better dead code elimination in the "include the source" case vs. the "link against the library" case? Sure, but if you're not using the symbols from the library, why link against it at all? I'm talking here about the general case, where you link against a library and, ya know, use the symbols exposed by it. Your example supports this.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is not as simple as you may think:

Let's do an experiment:

We will create a libfoo.a with the following structure:

Makefile:

```
LIBOUT=libfoo.a

SRC=foo1.c foo2.c foo3.c
OBJ=$(SRC:%.c=%.o)


default: test1 test2 test3

test1: $(LIBOUT)
    $(CC) -o $@ test1.c -L. -lfoo

test2: $(LIBOUT)
    $(CC) -o $@ test2.c -L. -lfoo

test3: $(LIBOUT)
    $(CC) -o $@ test3.c -L. -lfoo


$(LIBOUT): $(OBJ)
    $(AR) ruv $(LIBOUT) $(OBJ)
```

foo1.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo1_service_a() {
    printf("Performing foo1_service_a\n");
    return 0;
}
```

foo2.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo2_service_a() {
    printf("Performing foo2_service_a\n");
    return 0;
}
```

foo3.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo3_service_a() {
    printf("Performing foo3_service_a\n");
    return 0;
}

int foo3_service_b() {
    printf("Performing foo3_service_b\n");
    return 0;
}
```

And three test programs:

test1.c:

```
int main() {
    foo1_service_a();
    return 0;
}
```

test2.c:

```
int main() {
    foo2_service_a();
    return 0;
}
```

test3.c:

```
int main() {
    foo3_service_a();
    return 0;
}
```

When we compile them we get:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 masud users  285 Aug  3 16:42 Makefile
-rw-r--r--  1 masud users   96 Aug  3 16:38 foo1.c
-rw-r--r--  1 masud users 1496 Aug  3 16:39 foo1.o
-rw-r--r--  1 masud users   97 Aug  3 16:39 foo2.c
-rw-r--r--  1 masud users 1496 Aug  3 16:39 foo2.o
-rw-r--r--  1 masud users  173 Aug  3 16:39 foo3.c
-rw-r--r--  1 masud users 1688 Aug  3 16:40 foo3.o
-rw-r--r--  1 masud users 5008 Aug  3 16:40 libfoo.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 masud users 9132 Aug  3 16:43 test1
-rw-r--r--  1 masud users   45 Aug  3 16:43 test1.c
-rwxr-xr-x  1 masud users 9132 Aug  3 16:43 test2
-rw-r--r--  1 masud users   45 Aug  3 16:43 test2.c
-rwxr-xr-x  1 masud users 9251 Aug  3 16:43 test3
-rw-r--r--  1 masud users   45 Aug  3 16:43 test3.c
```

As you can tell that each of test1 test2 and test3 have foo1.o; foo2.o and foo3.o dictating their end sizes.

So it's the archive's content division that determines the size of the end binary.

### Exercise for the reader

What happens to the sizes when you strip the binaries? do test1 test2 and test3 become the same size?

Why or why not ? :)